# Server executes callback function, but client does not run function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, socket.io, callback

TLDR: I have tested a callback on a web socket (socketIO) function at multiple points of user input on a very large progressive web app, and the callback function takes a random amount of time (~1 second - indefinite seconds) to execute, while the server runs the function instantly. Is there any advice/pointers on how to pinpoint what is causing the callbacks to sometimes not run?

Background:
I am developing a progressive web app in React that performs various tasks, such as inventory control, project management, HR-related tasks, and so on. Because of this, the project has started to become very large, as there are many different tasks and processes all occurring at the same time.

*Why does this matter?*

I have been encountering a callback response (Server -> Client) issue for a while now, and I cannot discover its root cause. Since the app is very large, I need some guidance on what steps to take to pinpoint the source of the problem.

*The problem*

The main problem I am encountering is related to server-client communication. This app runs in React on the client side, uses socketIO to communicate to a server running Node.js, and then responds again using socketIO to the client. When communicating back, one of the most common methods used is callbacks. I pass a callback function to the socketIO emit, running that function once the task has been performed. For example, I ran this upon connection and when a user clicks a button:

```js
// App.js
// When the button is clicked (also called a socket. on('connection',...)
const handleClick = () => {
   socket.emit('MyEmit', (x)=>{
     // This line does not fire, or it takes 30 seconds - 1 minute to fire
     console.log("Well I fire:", x)
   })
}
```

```js
// Server.js
socket.on('MyEmit',(callBK)=>{
  console.log("Received MyEmit")
  // Timeout to represent API Call
  setTimeout(()=>{
    callBK({success:true, info: 'Received and Sent!'})
  },1000)
})
```

The problem is the callback on the `socket.on` in App.js the `console.log` sometimes does not fire or takes up to a few minutes to fire. This leads to specific server calls on the front end taking indefinitely long to execute, making the app unusable at points.

Since this is a large application, there is a lot of work going on in the main thread. Asynchronous style functions and lazy loading are implemented to help alleviate the problem, however, it is not a perfect solution as some tasks are very I/O data-heavy (the total amount of data handled in the app is ~ 500 MB - 1 GB). This reduces any blocking of animations and responsiveness, but background tasks tend to take longer. The callbacks take random amounts of time to execute on the front end however, as the `handleClick()` function fires on startup, its callback response time varies on each run.

The problem has become quite elusive, as it is not easily reproducible. Sometimes, the callbacks will immediately execute, sometimes they will take a minute, and sometimes there is no execution at all. It appears to be somewhat random, so here are the steps I have taken to narrow down the cause:

1. I have utilized Chrome's performance tab, and it has given me varied results. On startup, I see that many different Long tasks occur, however the app is still responsive. The majority of the Long tasks appear to be either node modules or rendering the different elements that appear on the screen. (on the picture, see the red boxes in the script evaluation, there are quite a few "Long Tasks")
   [image: Performance Tab]
   I do not have much knowledge of how to use the performance tasks, but I have followed the stack traces of the long tasks and they don't point to any section of code that I have written, so I assume that it mostly handles the various maps, objects, and other data formatting functions that I use to display data, however, I could use guidance on whether or not I am correct on assuming this.
2. I have also taken memory snapshots of the heap to get a better idea of the memory size, and it varies. Sometimes it is 1-2 GB, sometimes it is ~150 MB. This is probably due to a memory leak, but I do not think it is related to the callback issue so I have put that aside for now.
3. I also tested the callbacks in the different modules present in the app. I called the `socketIO` function on startup, on a module that requires almost no tasks running on the main thread, and the module that has the most tasks running on the main thread. All of them seem to give random response times, sometimes instantly executing the callback, and sometimes not at all. Even running the function on startup seems to vary in execution times.

On the server, the socket function runs instantly. There is no problem communicating through web sockets on the server, and the server does not slow down nor throw any errors. It executes the `socket.on` function and the callback response function immediately.

4. I tried out Chrome's lighthouse feature, and the two biggest red flags it throws are total blocking time and Javascript execution time. These are scored the lowest out of every other diagnostic, with bundle.js (testing the app on localhost) and script evaluation being the slowest of the individual metrics. This means that I need to re-evaluate my scripts and ensure I am developing functions with better time-complexities, but it isn't bad enough to the point where the app isn't responding due to a poorly designed script.

My investigation has led me to believe that 1 of 2 sources is causing this problem:

1. The pipe back from the server to the client (communication through `socketIO`)
2. The main thread is occupied to the point where it does not handle the asynchronous callback when it comes in

I understand that it is difficult to reproduce this on a different project, is there any advice on how to approach this problem? I have tried narrowing it down as much as possible, but due to the randomness of the bug, I am not 100% confident that these two sources are the cause.

Do web sockets struggle on clients that have a lot of main-thread work? I know that callback functions run asynchronously, but still require the thread running the browser to compile.

My version numbers:

- `socketIO` - 4.7.4 (on both the server and the client side)
- `React` - 18.2.0
- `Node.js` - 20.11.0

Comment: Try removing timeout function you added in server.js file. It works!

Comment: Hey @sachin, thanks for trying it out, I added the `setTimeout` function to "emulate" a API call, however with or without it the callbacks still sometimes do not execute on the client side

Comment: Yes, it would seem that your client is unusually busy with script evaluation for seconds. Try a beefier device to see if that improves speed (to validate the problem, not as a solution). Try to do more of the processing on your backend, or put it in worker threads, or at least chunk it up so that the main thread is more responsive to events (like your network responses, but it sounds like also processing of click and other ui events would be affected)